# How to manage business logic when building a REST API

Tags: rest, symfony, architecture, doctrine-orm

I'm building a API Centric web application but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around some of the business logic.

Take this Use Case:

```
POST /companies -> User adds a new Company which has a Location
```

(Company Entity has a Location Entity which keeps the address of the company, A Company has one Location, a location can have multiple Companies)

```
PATCH/PUT /companies/{id} -> User edits a Company information (changes street name from Company->Location
```

I want my API to be able to check if there are already other companies on that Location.
If this is the case, I want the user the chose between editing the Location Entity (which will change then for all Companies on that Location) or create a new Location.

How do I send this choice back to the User in a RESTful manner?

Answer (score 2):

easy :

- `PUT` replace the entire resource if it exists or create a new resource if it doesnt exist. there is no choice to be made if you want to stay strictly REST( but you dont have to) .it's up to your users to check if the company exists with a GET before a put.
- `POST` is suppose to replaced all the companies collection.
- You could use `PATCH` however to update an existing company.

see : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789

Comment: But it's not about the company, it's about the Location. A Location has multiple Companies. If a user changes the location I need to know if he really wants to change the Location entity (all connected Companies will have the edited Location data) or create a new Location.

Comment: there is a problem in your data model in my opinion. Why does a location has multiple companies ? it is should be the other way around. what do you call a location ?

Comment: Actually a Company has multiple Sites (e.g. Headquarters, Factory1, Factory2). Company and Site have a one-to-many relation. A Site has a many-to-one relation with Location (A Location can have multiple Sites). If you update a Location for a give company (relation set with Site) I want to check if the user wants to change the Location for all the companies attached to that Location using a Site or create a new Location but keep the same Site.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API or any strict service would provide a response based on a request. So the REST API can definitely respond back to the user if other companies are related to the location. But there is no way for the API to respond back with a choice. The API can respond back with some information and the user will need to make another request based on that information.

Instead, it is better to give the user the option to specify it upfront. So, the choice of whether related companies should be updated for the location is made upfront by the user as par of the request. For example, the user can specify this as a query param on the REST API and the service can take appropriate action based on that query param.

Comment: So maybe a GET /location/{id}/sites first to see if how many companies are using that location and if this is > 1 my front-end (AngularJS) will trigger a choice to either do a POST /location (Create a new Location) and then a PATCH /company/{id}/site (to update the Site to the new Location) OR a PATCH /location/{id} to just update the original Location. Is this a correct RESTful Approach?